# replacing a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, performance

I would like to find a way to replace a for loop that I am using. Quick version of my question is:
how can I go from a vector `[a,b,c,d,e]` to `[1,a,a*b,a*b*c,a*b*c*d]` ?
I currently do something like:

```
myvec <- c(.3,.5,.2,.3,.3)  
new_vec <- vector(length=length(myvec))  
new_vec[1] <- 1  
for (i in 2:length(myvec)) {  
    new_vec[i] <- myvec[i-1]*new_vec[i-1]  
}
```

However, this is extremely slow. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
c(1, cumprod(myvec))[1:length(myvec)]
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, that does exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Comment: do You happen to know how I can see the source code of cumprod? I am guessing that it is written in C?

Comment: Yes, it is written in C. I found an old version of the source here: http://www.google.com/codesearch#ETHLt0MjEm8/mirrors/Linux/Guadalinex/repositorio/pool/main/r/r-base/r-base_1.9.0.orig.tar.gz%7C1JYJfi7Ow9I/R-1.9.0/src/main/cum.c&q=r-base%20file:cum.c&type=cs but it's just really a cumulative product.

Comment: ok, thanks. It was more out of curiosity. I have often wanted to look at the source code of functions with .Primitive and never took the time to ask.

Comment: Probably not faster than for loops, but a higher level of abstraction that may be useful in other cases `Reduce("*", c(1, c(.3,.5,.2,.3,.3)  ), accumulate=T)`

Comment: @Andreas, Great solution, but shouldn't that be `c(1, cumprod(myvec))[1:(length(myvec)+1)]`?   The original question also needs `(length(myvec)) + 1)`.

Comment: @bill_080 In the original question the last element in the vector (e), is never actually used. I don't know if it's possible to see the edit history of my reply, but I added the [1:length(myvec)] after spotting that myself.

Comment: c(1,cumprod(myvec[seq(length(myvec)-1)])) probably fastest

Comment: what creative replies! Thank you to everyone. baptiste, Reduce looks like an interesting function. I don't understand it yet, but I will study it to learn it for the future as it looks useful. Ben Bolker, that is indeed the shortes. And good call Wojciech -- because I'm not using the last character, I shouldn't have cumprod use it either. Thanks!